# How to insert null values in primary key in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE  "QUIZQUES" 
   (    "QUESTION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "OPTION1" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "OPTION2" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "OPTION3" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "OPTION4" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "ANSWER" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "QUIZNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "QID" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
     CONSTRAINT "QUIZQUES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("QID") ENABLE
   )
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_QUIZQUES" 
  before insert on "QUIZQUES"               
  for each row  
begin   
    select "QUIZQUES_SEQ".nextval into :NEW.QID from dual; 
end; 
***************
```

Here I'm trying to insert null value into `QID`, but in myeclipse its showing  ORA-04098:

> trigger 'SYSTEM.BI_QUIZQUES' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Two things: (1) your trigger must be invalid for some reason, try entering `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER "BI_QUIZQUES"` in SQL*Plus, (2) don't create objects owned by the `SYSTEM` user.  Create another user and use that instead.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you create sequence `QUIZQUES_SEQ` as well? If yes, then please post your SQL code for it.